# Chrome's hidden CSS scroll-snap threshold and how to change it

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll

I have a container:

```
scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100%);
snap-type: mandatory;
snap-type: y mandatory;
```

And three children:

```
height: 100%;
scroll-snap-align: center;
scroll-snap-stop: always;
```

This works just as expected in Firefox, but there seems to be a threshold for snapping in Chrome. When scrolling just a small amount, Chrome will snap back to the first child, while Firefox will scroll to the next child. Only after scrolling about 30% of the child height, Chrome will snap to the next one.

This behavior can be seen in [this code pen](https://codepen.io/newinweb/pen/EpPgdR).

Is there any way to disable this hidden threshold and have Chrome scroll to the next child immediately?

Comment: Wondering the same! Just found out that Chrome has a really bad scroll threshold. It's super smooth in Firefox and even Chrome on Android... But on desktop it seems broken for a CSS scroll snap implementation using height 100% or 100vh

Comment: Ironically this seems to be the exact opposite on macOS. When using a track pad, Chrome feels smooth with a very low threshold, whereas Firefox seems to have an extremely high threshold, sometimes even scrolling down when I try to scroll up. When using a mouse, Chrome seems to have snapping disabled altogether, while Firefox simply jumps back and forth between panels without any kind of transition. macOS 10.12.6, Firefox 67.0.4, Chrome 76.0.3809.36.

Comment: What about safari on macOS, @Siguza?

Comment: Same as Chrome, @Ole.

Comment: Interesting. Currently experimenting with https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap
for a decent compromise. However, seeing that Chrome feels smooth on macOS, but not on Windows and Linux, it's not as simple as to just enable the "polyfill" when Chrome is detected...

Comment: Bah. No dice. Will do some attempts with addEventListener on scroll events tomorrow.

Comment: All my attempts the last few days have been for naught.
I've tried various versions of "if the user has scrolled a little, and nothing happened, scroll snap for them", but it quickly becomes wonky on touch devices.
I've tried going all out on the scroll-snap polyfill, but that too becomes wonky on touch devices.

Currently I'm wondering if I'll just attempt to open a ticket for Chrome, and/or implement a dirty blacklist using user agents...

Comment: There are quite a few [open Chromium bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/3897839768/hotlists/ScrollSnap-Polish) related to `scroll-snap`

Answer (score 7):

Based on the Chromium Bugs discussion around `scroll-snap` in general, it appears that the intent is to determine momentum (difficult with a scroll, slightly easier with a swipe) but the implementation is a bit wonky.

The suggestion is to utilize `scroll-snap-stop: always` to override that momentum intent (which you've done). However, it also mentions that `scroll-margin` and `scroll-padding` may impact the movement from one snap point to the next.

[CSS Snap Scrolling from Chrome Dev](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap)

You might also want to look at the [Overscroll-behavior API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior) in conjunction with `snap-scroll`.

Answer (score 3):

The threshold you describe seems to be closer to 50% with 75.0.3770.100 on (desktop) Linux.

I found that the old element would snap back if I scrolled the midpoint between two elements to just before the exact middle of the viewport, while the new element would scroll into view if I moved the midpoint to just after the exact middle of the viewport. Hence, it seems the threshold is 50%.

This behavior ***may*** be significantly related to the following:

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/cc/input/scroll_snap_data.cc?q=scroll-snap+&dr=C&l=152-155:

> ```
> // If snapping in one axis pushes off-screen the other snap area, this snap
> // position is invalid. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-snap-1/#snap-scope
> // In this case, we choose the axis whose snap area is closer, and find a
> // mutual visible snap area on the other axis.
> ```

I'm not sure.

I found the above searching for `snap-scroll`; most of the results for this query consist of HTML files and test mocks.

The other two relevant-looking results I found were

- https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/page/scrolling/snap_coordinator.cc?q=scroll-snap&dr=C&l=31
- https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/paint/paint_layer_scrollable_area.cc?q=scroll-snap&l=813&dr=C

Comment: Checked on my app - and YES - it is perfect now!

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily remove `scroll-snap-align` on `:hover` to make it go the next/previous, I guess:

```
#carousel.snap > div:hover {
  scroll-snap-align:initial;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXwYPa

Answer (score 0):

Certain issues like this can be solved by [`scroll-margin`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/) or scroll-padding.