# CSS scroll-snap-stop not working on chromium browsers?

Tags: html, css

I've looked around online in a lot of places and not found a definitive answer for this issue, with this code below, the scrolling on the web page automatically rolls down to the final snap point on chrome browsers. I've checked Firefox and that works 100% fine. The `scroll-snap-stop: always;` should be forcing the browser to not go beyond a single point, but even with a single notch on my scroll wheel, it drops all the way to the last point. however, it works fine when using the arrow keys to scroll. Is this an actual bug or am I doing something wrong here?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="section indexContent">
        <p>one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section indexContent">
        <p>two</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section indexContent">
        <p>three</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.indexContent {
  height: 100vh;
}
.section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629124/chromes-hidden-css-scroll-snap-threshold-and-how-to-change-it

Comment: @disinfor Thanks I hadn't come across that, though the issue still doesn't have a solution??

Comment: Then that's probably your answer - not all questions have a solution :)

Comment: ok well thanks dude, if anyone does have a work around to the same effect I would appreciate it