# Cannot change horizontal scroll snap into vertical scroll snap

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

I've found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/imjuangarcia/pen/zYORdMK), but It was Horizontal. When I was trying to make it vertical, it did not work.

[Pen](https://codepen.io/imjuangarcia/pen/zYORdMK) I found the code on:

```js
// None!
```

```css
/* Hide the scroll bars */

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slides {
  /* We set the scroll snapping */
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  /* Necessary for mobile scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* For layout purposes */
  display: flex;
  /* To allow horizontal scrolling */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

section {
  /* For styling purposes */
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Set where the snapping should happen */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}


/* Styling for the sections */

section h2 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-weight: 100;
}

section h3 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.section-1 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524260855046-f743b3cdad07?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1401&q=80')
}

.section-2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80')
}

.section-3 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1378&q=80')
}

.section-4 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501791330673-603715379ded?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')
}
```

```html
<main class="slides">
  <section class="section-1">
    <h2>Scroll right to see it in action </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-2">
    <h3>Woah! That's a cool effect!</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="section-3">
    <h2>And no Javascript! </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-4">
    <h3>How cool is that?</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

What I tried to change horizontal scroll snap into vertical scroll snap:

```js
// None!
```

```css
/* Hide the scroll bars */

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slides {
  /* We set the scroll snapping */
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  /* Necessary for mobile scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

section {
  /* For styling purposes */
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Set where the snapping should happen */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}


/* Styling for the sections */

section h2 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-weight: 100;
}

section h3 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.section-1 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524260855046-f743b3cdad07?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1401&q=80')
}

.section-2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80')
}

.section-3 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1378&q=80')
}

.section-4 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501791330673-603715379ded?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')
}
```

```html
<main class="slides">
  <section class="section-1">
    <h2>Scroll down to see it in action </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-2">
    <h3>Woah! That's a cool effect!</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="section-3">
    <h2>And no Javascript! </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-4">
    <h3>How cool is that?</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

I tried changing all the x's to y's, all y's to x's, and different combinations, but I still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent element doesn't have a fixed height and expands to fit the children. On top of that, you also need to set `overflow-y: scroll;` for parent element:

```js
// None!
```

```css
/* Hide the scroll bars */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slides {
  /* We set the scroll snapping */
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  /* Necessary for mobile scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  /* hide horizontal overflow */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* allow vertical overflow */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* set the height for parent, overwise it will expand to fit children */
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  /* For styling purposes */
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Set where the snapping should happen */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}


/* Styling for the sections */

section h2 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-weight: 100;
}

section h3 {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.section-1 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524260855046-f743b3cdad07?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1401&q=80')
}

.section-2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/34/BA1yLjNnQCI1yisIZGEi_2013-07-16_1922_IMG_9873.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80')
}

.section-3 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1378&q=80')
}

.section-4 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501791330673-603715379ded?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')
}
```

```html
<main class="slides">
  <section class="section-1">
    <h2>Scroll down to see it in action </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-2">
    <h3>Woah! That's a cool effect!</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="section-3">
    <h2>And no Javascript! </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-4">
    <h3>How cool is that?</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

Other css properties were added for aestetics only, feel free to ignore.

Comment: Is it possible to snap while you are scrolling? The same as the one I found in the pen except virtical.

Comment: It already does that, might be not very obvious on small result display. Check the answer in `Full page` (small link which appears next to the buttons when you run code snippet)

Comment: I clicked full page, the the problem still remains.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It works the way you want in Firefox, but not Chrome. Let me check.

Comment: The behaviour of Chrome has already been discussed here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629124/chromes-hidden-css-scroll-snap-threshold-and-how-to-change-it